# How to Apply Styles at runtime in Childwindow in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I am not able to apply style at runtime on child window.I have created two styles one with chrome and one without chrome. What i wanted to do is on mediaplayer fullscreen mode disable the dragging of child window and on press on escape button(normal mode) enable dragging of child window.
My code looks like this :

```
void Content_FullScreenChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        if (App.Current.Host.Content.IsFullScreen)
        {

            ObjChildMediaPlayer.Style  = Application.Current.Resources["TestStyle"] as Style;
        }
        else
        {

            ObjChildMediaPlayer.Style  = Application.Current.Resources["TestBasicStyle"] as Style;                

        }

        ObjChildMediaPlayer.UpdateLayout();
    }
```

On full screen dragging is disabling but when i press escape button it does not drag. I want the child window to be dragging in normal mode.

Comment: Its impossible to diagnose without seeing the content of the styles.

Answer (score 0):

TestStyle :

```
<Style x:Key ="TestStyle" TargetType="controls:ChildWindow">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Cycle" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="OverlayBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#7F000000" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="OverlayOpacity" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:ChildWindow">
                <Grid x:Name="Root">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1F3B53" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="15" Height="14" Background="#02FFFFFF" x:Name="grid">
                                            <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="X" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.95" />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </vsm:VisualState>
                                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="X" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.85" />
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </vsm:VisualState>
                                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="X" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.5" />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </vsm:VisualState>
                                                </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                                            </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Width="9" Fill="#14C51900" Stretch="Fill" Data="F1 M 6.742676,3.852539 L 9.110840,1.559570 L 8.910645,0.500000 L 6.838379,0.500000 L 4.902832,2.435547 L 2.967285,0.500000 L 0.895020,0.500000 L 0.694824,1.559570 L 3.062988,3.852539 L 0.527832,6.351563 L 0.689941,7.600586 L 2.967285,7.600586 L 4.897949,5.575195 L 6.854004,7.600586 L 9.115723,7.600586 L 9.277832,6.351563 L 6.742676,3.852539 Z" x:Name="X_Fuzz2" Stroke="#14C51900" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                                <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                    <TransformGroup>
                                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.3" ScaleY="1.3" />
                                                    </TransformGroup>
                                                </Path.RenderTransform>
                                            </Path>
                                            <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Width="9" Fill="#1EC51900" Stretch="Fill" Data="F1 M 6.742676,3.852539 L 9.110840,1.559570 L 8.910645,0.500000 L 6.838379,0.500000 L 4.902832,2.435547 L 2.967285,0.500000 L 0.895020,0.500000 L 0.694824,1.559570 L 3.062988,3.852539 L 0.527832,6.351563 L 0.689941,7.600586 L 2.967285,7.600586 L 4.897949,5.575195 L 6.854004,7.600586 L 9.115723,7.600586 L 9.277832,6.351563 L 6.742676,3.852539 Z" x:Name="X_Fuzz1" Stroke="#1EC51900" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                                <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                    <TransformGroup>
                                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.1" ScaleY="1.1" />
                                                    </TransformGroup>
                                                </Path.RenderTransform>
                                            </Path>
                                            <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Width="9" Fill="#FFC51900" Stretch="Fill" Data="F1 M 6.742676,3.852539 L 9.110840,1.559570 L 8.910645,0.500000 L 6.838379,0.500000 L 4.902832,2.435547 L 2.967285,0.500000 L 0.895020,0.500000 L 0.694824,1.559570 L 3.062988,3.852539 L 0.527832,6.351563 L 0.689941,7.600586 L 2.967285,7.600586 L 4.897949,5.575195 L 6.854004,7.600586 L 9.115723,7.600586 L 9.277832,6.351563 L 6.742676,3.852539 Z" x:Name="X_Fuzz0" Stroke="#FFC51900" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="1" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                            <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Width="9" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Stretch="Fill" Data="F1 M 6.742676,3.852539 L 9.110840,1.559570 L 8.910645,0.500000 L 6.838379,0.500000 L 4.902832,2.435547 L 2.967285,0.500000 L 0.895020,0.500000 L 0.694824,1.559570 L 3.062988,3.852539 L 0.527832,6.351563 L 0.689941,7.600586 L 2.967285,7.600586 L 4.897949,5.575195 L 6.854004,7.600586 L 9.115723,7.600586 L 9.277832,6.351563 L 6.742676,3.852539 Z" x:Name="X" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0.7">
                                                <Path.Stroke>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF313131" Offset="1" />
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8E9092" Offset="0" />
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Path.Stroke>
                                            </Path>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="WindowStates">
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Open">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Overlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3" Value="1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(Children)[0].ScaleX">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="0" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="1" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0,0,0.5,1" KeyTime="00:00:00.45" Value="1.05" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.55" Value="1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(Children)[0].ScaleY">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="0" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="1" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0,0,0.5,1" KeyTime="00:00:00.45" Value="1.05" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.55" Value="1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Overlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3" Value="0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(Children)[0].ScaleX">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="1.05" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.45" Value="0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(Children)[0].ScaleY">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="1.05" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.45" Value="0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                    </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="Overlay" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0" Background="{TemplateBinding OverlayBrush}" Opacity="{TemplateBinding OverlayOpacity}" />
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform />
                                <SkewTransform />
                                <RotateTransform />
                                <TranslateTransform />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="#14000000" Background="#14000000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-1" />
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2.25" BorderBrush="#0F000000" Background="#0F000000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2.5" BorderBrush="#0C000000" Background="#0C000000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2.75" BorderBrush="#0A000000" Background="#0A000000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <Border Background="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="2">
                            <Border CornerRadius="1.5" Margin="1">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E8EB" Offset="1" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF6F8F9" Offset="0" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                                <Grid IsHitTestVisible="True" >
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Border x:Name="Chrome" Width="Auto" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,0.528" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E8EB" Offset="1" />
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFEFEFE" Offset="0" />
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                        <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Other style does not have chrome rest everything is same.